# Asp.net MVC 2.0 TempData expiration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

What happens in Asp.Net MVC 2.0, when next request does not come ever to retrieve value from TempData. Is it stored permanently or expires?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `TempData` is stored in session it will expire along with the session. Also note that `TempData` is not expired when it is retrieved but on the next request no matter whether you access it or no.

Comment: What's the difference bewteen TempData and Session variable then ?

Comment: @Kris-I, information stored in TempData lasts only between one redirect whereas Session is for the entire lifetime of the session. Internally TempData uses Session for storage but it automatically expires the data you have stored after a redirect.